# Make trick to rebuild binaries without being PHONY

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a set of files that sometimes need to be regenerated.  Standard make stuff.  I have a rule that knows how to regenerate.

`$(foreach x, $(BIG_LIST), $(eval $(x): $(x).in))
$(BIG_LIST):
    opaque_binary -o $@ $^`

This works well enough.  The problem is that `opaque_binary` also sometimes needs to rebuilt - and I can not express its dependencies.  Specifically it is a Go binary (go handles rebuild deps internally) and it can take 4-5 seconds for Go to figure out "nothing to do here".  I can't simply rebuild it in my recipe - too slow.

Currently I just run it unilaterally from my `all` rule, which is annoying because most of the time it is up to date and I don't need to regen my BIG_LIST anyway.  Time wasted.

Worse, I have about a half dozen such binaries to build, so this step ends up taking upwards of 30 seconds to effectively do nothing.

I'm hoping there's some way express "do this one time, but only if any of the files in BIG_LIST need to be regenerated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got enough of the problem scenario straight from the question and your comments
(and maybe I haven't), then:

- The members of `$(BIG_LIST)` are in fact subdirectories of the `make` directory
- Your targets are files uniformly located in those subdirectories, but the
  prerequisites of those targets are not pattern-wise constructible from the targets:
  they can only be identified by running a shell process in the subdirectory.
- The "opaque binary" is needed to execute the recipe for each target. *But!* It
  is out-of-date and must be rebuilt, first, if it is older than any of the *prerequisites*.

Rather you than me! Anyhow, to a first approximation you need the "opaque_binary" to be:-

- be an [order-only pre-requisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
  of your targets: *not* of the sub-directories.
- dependent on all the prerequisites of your targets.

You are of course right in concluding that you can't use pattern rules if you can't nail the
patterns. But it doesn't follow that you must go with `$(foreach subdir,$(subdirs),$(eval ...))`.
Better to take advantage of the fact that in a makefile *you can generate an auxiliary makefile that
you subsequently* `include`. If you have the choice, generated rules and recipes that you save to generated makefile
are preferable to ones generated only in memory by `$(eval ...)` because they are
vastly more *scrutable*.

For illustratation, pretend the opaque binary is `copy`, a trivial
C program built from `copy.c` that merely copies the file named by its first argument to the standard output.
You say you can't really express the making of the opaque binary in the makefile,
but you know some way of making it, so we'll just assume it's the way that `copy` is made (which is
slightly unorthodox in the interest of clearer `make` output).

Here's a makefile for a project in which existing subdirectories `$(dirs)` each contain
some `*.x` file that we pretend we can only identify by looking. From this `*.x` file
we want to make `foo.out` in the same subdirectory using `copy`, but `copy` must first be
rebuilt if is older than the `*.x` file. Just for our present convenience the makefile
also provides for making the `$(dirs)` and the `*.x` files from scratch.

**Makefile (take 1)**

```
dirs := a b c
file := foo
for_convenience := \
    $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
        $(shell mkdir -p $(dir) && ([ -f $(dir)/file.x ] || \
        echo "$(dir)/file.x content" > $(dir)/file.x)))
outs := $(dirs:%=%/$(file).out)
opaque_binary := copy
void := $(file >gen_rules.mk,)
void := \
    $(foreach dir,$(dirs), \
        $(file >>gen_rules.mk,\
            $(dir:%=%/$(file).out): $(shell ls $(dir)/*.x) | \
            $(opaque_binary); ./$(opaque_binary) $$< > $$@))
void := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
            $(file >>gen_rules.mk,\
                $(opaque_binary): $(shell ls $(dir)/*.x)))


.PHONY: all clean test

all: $(outs)

$(opaque_binary): copy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -fr $(dirs) $(opaque_binary)

test:
    cat $(outs)

include gen_rules.mk
```

By the time `make` executes any target it will have generated `gen_rules.mk`, which
will look like:

**gen_rules.mk**

```
 a/foo.out: a/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
 b/foo.out: b/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
 c/foo.out: c/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
 copy: a/file.x
 copy: b/file.x
 copy: c/file.x
```

Because `$(opaque_binary)` i.e. `copy` is an order-only pre-requisite of the `$(outs)`, 
it will *not* be considered when determining whether any of the `$(outs)` needs to be remade, 
but it *will* be made before any of the `$(outs)`, and it has dependencies on all of the `*.x` 
files that will trigger its recipe if it is older than any of them.

From scratch, `make` looks like:

```
$ make
cc  -o copy copy.c  
./copy a/file.x > a/foo.out
./copy b/file.x > b/foo.out
./copy c/file.x > c/foo.out
```

where you can see that as soon `a/foo.out` needs to be made, `copy` is made first,
and then isn't remade for `b/foo.out` or `c/foo.out`, because it doesn't need to be.

Just to show that `$(opaque_binary)` has done its stuff:

```
$ make test
cat a/foo.out b/foo.out c/foo.out
a/file.x content
b/file.x content
c/file.x content
```

If we update any of the `*.x` files then `$(opaque_binary)` is remade, just once:

```
$ touch a/file.x b/file.x
$ make
cc  -o copy copy.c  
./copy a/file.x > a/foo.out
./copy b/file.x > b/foo.out
```

**Will that do?**

This may well be enough for you, if the makefile is only intended ever to
make all of the `$(outs)` at the same time.

If it's also intended for making individual `$(outs)` or subsets of `$(outs)`,
then there remains a margin for pointless builds of the `$(opaque_binary)` that
you might want to excise. E.g.

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

All good. Then Agent A updates `a/file.x`:

```
$ touch a/file.x
```

Agent B makes `b/foo.out`, *which is up-to-date*:

```
$ make b/foo.out
cc -o copy copy.o
```

Because `$(opaque_binary)` depends on *all* the `*.x` files, Agent B has been charged 1 build of `$(opaque_binary)` 
that they didn't ask for and don't need. And gallingly, that gratuitous charge is their *entire* bill.

By the [Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering),
you can remedy this waste and injustice by introducing an extra level of indirection,
as in:

**Makefile (take 2)**

```
dirs := a b c
file := foo
for_convenience := \
    $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
        $(shell mkdir -p $(dir) && ([ -f $(dir)/file.x ] || \
        echo "$(dir)/file.x content" > $(dir)/file.x)))
outs := $(dirs:%=%/$(file).out)
opaque_binary := copy
void := $(file >gen_rules_pass1.mk,)
void := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
            $(file >>gen_rules_pass1.mk,\
                $(dir:%=%/$(file).out): $(shell ls $(dir)/*.x) | \
                $(opaque_binary); ./$(opaque_binary) $$< > $$@))
void := $(file >gen_rules_pass0.mk,)
void := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
            $(file >>gen_rules_pass0.mk,\
                $(dir:%=%/$(file).out): $(shell ls $(dir)/*.x)))
void := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
            $(file >>gen_rules_pass0.mk,\
                $(dir:%=%/$(file).out): $(dir:%=%.$(opaque_binary).d); $$(MAKE) $$@))
void := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),\
            $(file >>gen_rules_pass0.mk,\
                $(dir:%=%.$(opaque_binary).d: $(shell ls $(dir)/*.x)); \
                rm -f $(opaque_binary); touch $$@))
deps := $(dirs:%=%.$(opaque_binary).d)

.PHONY: all clean test

ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),1)
all: $(outs)

include gen_rules_pass1.mk

else

all : $(deps)
    $(MAKE)

include gen_rules_pass0.mk

endif

$(opaque_binary): copy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(deps) $(ins) $(outs) $(opaque_binary) gen_rules_pass*.mk

test:
    cat $(outs)
```

Here we need a two-pass make, so we generate `gen_rules_pass0.mk` for inclusion
when `$(MAKELEVEL)` == 0 and `gen_rules_pass1.mk` for inclusion when `$(MAKELEVEL)` == 1.

**gen_rules_pass0.mk**

```
 a/foo.out: a/file.x
 b/foo.out: b/file.x
 c/foo.out: c/file.x
 a/foo.out: a.copy.d; $(MAKE) $@
 b/foo.out: b.copy.d; $(MAKE) $@
 c/foo.out: c.copy.d; $(MAKE) $@
 a.copy.d: a/file.x; rm -f copy; touch $@
 b.copy.d: b/file.x; rm -f copy; touch $@
 c.copy.d: c/file.x; rm -f copy; touch $@
```

Here you see, for each target-stem `T` we've introduced a *dependency file* `T.$(opaque_binary).d`
that provides a *per*-`T/foo.out: T/file.x`-*pair* target on which we can hang the determination
of whether `$(opaque_binary)` shall be rebuilt. If `T/foo.out` has been out-dated by `T/file.x`
it will trigger the recipe:

```
 T/foo.out: T.copy.d; $(MAKE) $@
```

which will remake `T/foo.out` in the second pass. And it will also require:

```
T.copy.d: T/file.x; rm -f copy; touch $@
```

to be evaluated first, whence if `T.copy.d` is likewise outdated by `T/file.x`,
then `$(opaque_binary)` will be deleted in *this* pass and `T.copy.d`'s
timestamp updated. For the default target, this pass just remakes all the
`T.$(opaque_binary).d`s and then calls the second pass. Otherwise the
rules for the specified `T/foo.out` targets kick in.

**gen_rules_pass1.mk**

```
 a/foo.out: a/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
 b/foo.out: b/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
 c/foo.out: c/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
```

As compared to the old `gen_rules.mk`, its got the same:

```
 T/foo.out: T/file.x | copy; ./copy $< > $@
```

and none of the:

```
copy: T/file.x
```

We've no more need to make `$(opaque_binary)` depend on the
`*.x` files since the first pass has either preserved or
deleted it exactly as our targets require. But as it remains an
order-only prerequisite of any of those targets, it is now going to
be remade if it needs to be, because if it needs to be, it's gone.

With this makefile, `make` from scratch looks like:

```
$ make
rm -f copy; touch a.copy.d
rm -f copy; touch b.copy.d
rm -f copy; touch c.copy.d
make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
cc  -o copy copy.c  
./copy a/file.x > a/foo.out
./copy b/file.x > b/foo.out
./copy c/file.x > c/foo.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
```

And after updating some `*.x` files:

```
$ touch a/file.x b/file.x
$ make
rm -f copy; touch a.copy.d
rm -f copy; touch b.copy.d
make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
cc  -o copy copy.c  
./copy a/file.x > a/foo.out
./copy b/file.x > b/foo.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
```

So far, so much like before. But if we replay the Agent A, Agent B
scenario:

```
$ make
make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
$ touch a/file.x    # Agent A
$ make b/foo.out    # Agent B
make: 'b/foo.out' is up to date.    # :)
```

and:

```
make a/foo.out
rm -f copy; touch a.copy.d
make a/foo.out
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
cc  -o copy copy.c  
./copy a/file.x > a/foo.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
```

which is more efficient and fair than before, though by means that are more complex and less robust.

You may dislike the `make` directory being cluttered with the `*.d` files
and, more practically, worry about the ease with which idle hands might
mess them up. On that account dependency files like these are usually
secreted in a hidden `.d` or `.deps` subdirectory. I've ommitted that
precaution for simplicity.

Even if I haven't grokked the problem quite correctly, the ideas here may help you to a solution.

(GNU Make 4.1)

Comment: This is a staggering response.  I will need some time to digest it, but I am accepting it for now :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that fragment looks weird to me. Why not simply a static pattern rule?

```
$(BIG_LIST): %: %.in
    opaque_binary -o $@ $^
```

As to the matter at hand, when go has finally figured out it has "nothing to do here", I bet it won't update the timestamp of the binary. Then the fact it did all that evaluation needs to be recorded in some other way, e.g. by updating the timestamp yourself. And then we need to re-evaluate if any of the .in files changed after that.

So this is how I wrote it:

```
$(BIG_LIST): %: %.in | opaque_binary
        opaque_binary -o $@ $^

opaque_binary: $(BIG_LIST:%=%.in)
        have a go at $@
        copy /B $@+,,
```

You can abbreviate `opaque_binary` with `$|` in the recipe.

Comment: The reason I can't use a static pattern is that I lied (tried to simplify).  The pattern is actually `$(BIG_LIST): %/out.generated : $(shell ls %/*.go | grep -v generated)`, wherein make does not expand the wildcard, so I figure out to use `$(foreach dir, $(BIG_LIST), 
    $(eval $(dir)/out.generated): $(shell ls $(dir)/*.go | grep -v generated)))`.  I am not happy about it, but it was the best I could figure and it works.

Comment: Because my .in is really a directory, this gives me the two-run problem.  First time through, it finds the need to regenerate, makes the opaque_binary, generates the output file which touches the dir.  The next make finds the dir is dirty, so rebuilds the binary but finds the actual input files are not dirty so does not regen.  This is close though!!

Comment: I too give up on getting rid of eval here... but I would still avoid shell and use something like `$(foreach dir, $(BIG_LIST), $(eval $(dir)/out.generated: $(filter-out $(dir)/generated%.go, $(wildcard $(dir)/*.go))))`, but of course that is not the same if that grep needs to be really substringy.